# React Native i18n not working with Alert?

Tags: react-native

I am using react native with expo ,
I need multi language in my app , and I had notice one thing,which is when i need to pop up a alert , I am not able to make the title and the message of the alert box with {i18n.t('gift_home.title_hide_a_gift')} ..

For example :

```
<Menu.Item onPress ={()=>{Alert.alert("Repot user","Are you sure？",
       [
         {text:"Yes",onPress:() =>console.log("Yes")},
         {text : "No" ,onPress :() => console.log("No")},
       ])}} title="Report"/>
```

Anyone can help ?? Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here full example can help you.

try snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/i18n) (worked in android && ios not web)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';


// Set the key-value pairs for the different languages you want to support.
i18n.translations = {
  en: { title : 'Hello' }, //en definintion here
  ja: { title: 'こんにちは' },//ja definintion here
};
// Set the locale once at the beginning of your app.
i18n.locale = "en";//Localization.locale;


export default function App() {


  return (
    <View style={{flex : 1, padding : 8, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Button 
          title="click me"
          onPress ={
            ()=>{
              Alert.alert(
                i18n.t("title"), //usage here
                "Are you sure？",
                [
                  {text:"Yes", onPress:() =>console.log("Yes")},
                  {text : "No", onPress :() => console.log("No")},
                ]
              )
          }}>

      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]